# AngularJs - Link rel stylesheet is not being used inside ui-view

Tags: angularjs

> THE **LINK REL STYLESHEET CSS** does not reflect the css of `login.html` inside the UI VIEW

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- IMPORT -->       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/index.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="test" ui-view>

</body>
<script src="lib\angular\angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib\angular\angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib\angular\angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="app\app.js"></script>    
<script src="app\router\router.js"></script>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.turnBlack {
    background: black;
}
```

**ROUTER JS**

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("login", {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "app/view/login.html",
            controller: "loginController"
        })
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login'); // ALSO THE OTHERWISE IS NOT WORKING
}])
```

**LOGIN.HTML**

> The div has to be background black

```
<div class="turnBlack">
   I WANT TO BE BLACK
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `ng-class="turnBlack"` instead of `class="turnBlack"`.

Comment: No need to use `ng-class` for static class names